# Match global, but only if line starts with a specific string

Tags: regex, pcre

I feel like this should be very simple, and I'm missing a single, important bit.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/lXh5Vj/1

Regex,  using /m/g flags:

```
^GROUPS.*?"(?<name>[^:]+):(?<id>\d+)"
```

Test string:

```
GROUPS: ["group1:44343", "group2:23324", "group3:66567"]
USERS: ["user1:44343", "user2:23324", "user3:66567"]
```

My current regex will only match group1, because only that group is directly preceded by "GROUPS". I interpret this as "Global matching" meaning it will only start to check the string again after the first match. As there is no "GROUPS" between group1 and group2, group2 is not a match. If I alter the test string and add "GROUPS" before group2, this will also match, supporting my suspicion. But I do not know how to alter global matching handling to always consider the start of the line GROUPS.

The Regex should match 3  and 3  in the first line, and none in the second. If I remove the "GROUPS" part from the regex, the groups are matched just fine, but then also match the second line, which I do not want.

Comment: What about multiple matches with `(?:\G(?!\A)|^GROUPS).*?"\K(?<name>[^:]+):(?<id>\d+)"`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nsKeGM/1).

Comment: Or with the square brackets `(?:^GROUPS[^"]*\[(?=[^][]*])"|\G(?!^))(?<name>[^:]+):(?<id>\d+)"` https://regex101.com/r/aBQvKu/1

Comment: Please provide answers as answers, not comments :) . Wiktor: Your solution works great! The fourth bird: Your solution matches the ", " before the groupnames as well, so not ideal.

Comment: @Senshi Yea the posted answer is a different one. I will remove the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match `GROUPS: ["` at the start of the string, and the key:value parts in named groups, you can make use of the `\G` anchor.

```
(?:^GROUPS:\h*\["(?=[^][]*])|\G(?!^),\h*")(?<name>[^:]+):(?<id>\d+)"
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^GROUPS:\h*\[` Start of string, Match `GROUPS:` optional spaces and `[`
  - `"(?=[^][]*])` Match `"` and assert a closing `]` at the right
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^),\h*"` Assert the position at the end of the previous match (to get consecutive groups) and match a comma, optional spaces and `"`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?<name>[^:]+)` Named group `name` Match 1+ times any char except `:`
- `:` Match literally
- `(?<id>\d+)` Named group `id`, match 1+ digits
- `"` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CtsDLC/1)

Comment: Works great! Thank you as well for explaining what the individual parts do. Fixed my issue and made me learn something.